# storing templated parameter pack in std::function object

Tags: c++, c++11, logging, variadic-functions, std-function

I have developed a library which is used in other libraries and applications.
Its up for the application to provide the actual logging facility. The library shall only define a set of verbosity levels and pass the message to the application if something happened that should be logged.
Hence my idea is to store a `std::function` object in my library that actually points to some callback in the client application. Note in prior that C style variadic template arguments accessed via `va_start, va_list` and `va_end` are no option. This is because the client may use a non-printf based scheme such as `spdlog` does as an example. I am aware of not providing a MWE but that is because the code does not even compile.

library:

```
.hpp
enum class severity_t
{
    trace = 0,
    debug = 1,
    warn = 2,
    error = 3,
    critical = 4
};

template <typename ...args_t>
using logging_callback_t = std::function<void(severity_t, std::string, args_t...)>;

template <typename ...args_t>
extern logging_callback_t<args_t...> logging_callback;

template <typename ...args_t>
void log(severity_t level, const std::string& msg, args_t&& ...args)
{
    logging_callback<args_t...>(level, msg, std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
}

template <typename ...args_t>
void set_logging_cbk(logging_callback_t<args_t...> func)
{
    logging_callback<args_t...> = func;
}

.cpp
template <typename ...args_t>
logging_callback_t<args_t...> logging_callback;

std::string to_append("something");
log(severity_t::warn, "abc {}", to_append);
```

client application:

```
template <typename ...args_t)
void log_from_lib_a(severity_t level, const std::string& msg, args_t&& args...)
{
    if(level == severity_t::warn)
    {
        spdlog::warn(msg, std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
    }
}


int main()
{
    set_logging_cbk<???>(boost::bind(&log_from_lib_a<???&...>, 
                                     boost::placeholders::_1, 
                                     boost::placeholders::_2,
                                       ???);
}
```

The only place in code I know about the actual type of the variadic template parameters is while logging from within the library. How can the client register for a callback he does not know the arguments for? This is the first time for me to use a parameter pack so I hope the code/idea is at least somehow reasonable.
Apart from that why is it necessary to specify the variadic paramter type when calling a method on an instance of the std::function:

```
logging_callback<args_t...>(level, msg, std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
```

instead of

```
logging_callback(level, msg, std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
```

PS: cstd++11 is required, still if there is a better solution with a more recent version I am happy to hear about it too!

Comment: Please write [MRE]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a virtual template method, which is mostly what you want with type erasure behind `std::function`.

As you control your library, you know each prototype really used, so you might create a logger interface matching your needs:

```
struct ILogger
{
    virtual ~ILogger() = default;

    virtual void write(severity_t, const std::string&) = 0;
    virtual void write(severity_t, const std::string&, int) = 0;
    virtual void write(severity_t, const std::string&, int, const std::string&) = 0;
    virtual void write(severity_t, const std::string&, float) = 0;
    // ...
};

void set_logger(ILogger&); // custom point
```

Then provide a way to easily create a class from a variadic functor, something like:

```
template <typename Functor>
struct LoggerT : ILogger, Functor
{
    using Functor::Functor;
    using Functor::operator();

    void write(severity_t level, const std::string& format) override { (*this)(level, format);}
    void write(severity_t level, const std::string& format, int v1) override { (*this)(level, format, v1);}
    void write(severity_t level, const std::string& format, int v1, const std::string& v2) override { (*this)(level, format, v1, v2);}
    void write(severity_t level, const std::string& format, float v1) override { (*this)(level, format, v1);}
    // ...
};

template <typename Func>
LoggerT<Func> make_logger(Func func) { return {func}; }
```

Then your client just have to write:

```
struct SpdLogger {
    template <typename ... Ts>
    void operator () (severity_t level, const std::string& msg, Ts&& args...)
    {
        if (level == severity_t::warn)
        {
            spdlog::warn(msg, std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    LoggerT<SpdLogger> logger;
    set_logger(logger);
    // ...
}
```

and in C++14, with generic lambda:

```
auto logger = make_logger([](severity_t level, const std::string& msg, auto&& args...)
    {
        if(level == severity_t::warn)
        {
            spdlog::warn(msg, decltype(args)(args)...); // decltype(args) is the forward
        }
    });
set_logger(logger);
```